# AnnotationChart dateformat from sqlserver

Tags: sql, datetime, google-visualization, data-visualization

Hi Im trying to implement an Annotation chart that get its data from Sql Server. The code is working as the data is coming back . My problem is the format of the date / datetime when doing google.visualization.DataTable().addRow()

The date format returned from sqlserver is 2014-03-19 12:00:00 AM

How to change this date format to insert into the datatable.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load('visualization', '1.1', { packages: ['annotationchart'] });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: 'Default.aspx/GetData',
                data: '{}',
                success:
                    function (response) {
                        drawVisualization(response.d);
                    }

            });
        })

        function drawVisualization(dataValues) {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('datetime', 'Column Name');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Column Value');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Column Value2');

            console.log(dataValues[0].ColumnName);



            for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
                data.addRow([dataValues[i].ColumnName, dataValues[i].Value, dataValues[i].Value2]);
            }


           var formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: 'yyyy-MM-dd'});

                 var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));

        var options = {
          displayAnnotations: false,
        };

        chart.draw(data, options);



         }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="visualization" style="width: 1000px; height: 500px;">
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the C# code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Configuration;
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static List<Data> GetData()
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(****);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        conn.Open();
        string cmdstr = "select LogDate, val1, val2from [vwTest]";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adp.Fill(ds);
        dt = ds.Tables[0];
        List<Data> dataList = new List<Data>();
        string cat = "";
        int val = 0;
        int val2 = 0;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            cat = dr[0].ToString();
            val = Convert.ToInt32(dr[1]);
            val2 = Convert.ToInt32(dr[2]);
            DateTime dte = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Parse(cat).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
            dataList.Add(new Data(dte, val, val2));//Dont know what to do here
        }
        return dataList;
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public DateTime ColumnName;
        public int Value = 0;
        public int Value2 = 0;
        public Data(DateTime columnName, int value, int value2)
        {
            ColumnName = columnName;
            Value = value;
            Value2 = value2;
        }
    }
}
```

I see examples where people use new Date(2013,23,3,4,5) say but im not hard coding my data.

Please assist. This is my first Attempt at Google Visualization API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates are tricky to work with when you are sending data via JSON (since JSON does not have a date standard).  The only way to get them input as proper Date objects is to use the full JSON DataTable syntax for specifying rows, columns, and cells of data.  Since I'm not quite sure how this would be done in C#, I have an alternative approach I can demonstrate for you.  Since you need Date objects for your DataTable, and your output is giving you date strings, it is a relatively simple task to parse the strings into year, month, and day, and then build a Date object from those:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
    // assumes the date string is in the format "yyyy-MM-dd"
    var dateArr = dataValues[i].ColumnName.split('-');
    var year = dateArr[0];
    var month = dateArr[1] - 1; // adjust for javascript's 0-indexed months
    var day = dateArr[2];
    data.addRow([new Date(year, month, day), dataValues[i].Value, dataValues[i].Value2]);
}
```

Comment: ok thank you for the approach. I ended up sending the date broken up from sql server and built it up like you said. Thanks for replying. your way will work as well.